# Draw cylinder with linear gradient texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

How can I draw a cylinder in OpenGL which has a linear gradient texture that is oriented like the one in this example image ([link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agwt2.png))?

I use gluCylinder() to draw the cylinder. But I struggle to get the texture right.

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D);
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, texture);
GLubyte gradient[6] = { 255,0,0, 0,255,0 };
glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, gradient);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

gluQuadricDrawStyle(quad,GLU_FILL);
gluQuadricTexture(quad,GL_TRUE);
gluCylinder(quad,1.0f,1.0f,3.0f,32,32);
```

This produces a gradient, but it has the wrong orientation: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWPAA.png)

How can I get the correct orientation?

Comment: Do you already have some code, or are you completely new to OpenGL? If it's the latter, you gotta start at a lower level, as we won't just write some code for you that you cannot really understand.

Comment: Head to NeHe OpenGL tutorials, all basic things are explained there -> http://nehe.gamedev.net/lesson.asp?index=01

Comment: I am not new to OpenGL. I updated the question to provide more information and code.

Comment: This actually looks like you need no texture at all. The gradient seems to go from pure red to pure green (I do have a slight color vision deficiency, so bear with me if I'm wrong...), which can be done by interpolating vertex colors. Give all vertices in one "ring" one color, and all vertices in the other "ring" the other color. The vertex shader will interpolate that color on the cylinder between the "rings" (works the same with texture coordinates anyway).

Comment: I agree with @Damon , you could just draw it yourself using a loop. That way you'll be able to control the vertex colors at each end.
If that's too inefficient, then you can use vertex buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply some texture coordinates. I don't remember which texture coordinates gluCylinder generates, if any at all. But in your case old style OpenGL texture coordinate generation should serve you. gluCylinder goes along the Z axis, so we need texture coordinates mapping (0,0,0)→(0) to (0,0,heigt)→(1).

OpenGL up to version 2 provides texture coordinate generation, so I suggest the following to add before calling gluCylinder, instead of gluQuadricTexture.

```
GLfloat texgen_coeff[4] = {1./height, 0., 0., 0.};
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_S, GL_OBJECT_PLANE, texgen_coeff);
```